# Getting GTalk and Alt-Tab to play nice

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I'm running GTalk on Windows 7, and it refuses to work properly with Alt-Tab.

Let's say I've got 2 message windows open (msg1 and msg2) and the contact list, as well as 
Firefox. Alt-tab from Firefox to msg1 works, but now the contact list is the most recent thing in the alt-tab list (not Firefox as expected). Then there's the problem that I can't use alt-tab to select a specific message window, and when switching back to msg2 (showing msg2 in the alt-tab window) it might switch back and have focus on msg1.

I found [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Talk/thread?tid=06527da73b2d92b0&hl=en) complaining about the same problem, but it's over a year old, and I'm hoping some progress has been made.

Comment: This does my freaking head in. Never looked at fixing it though

Answer (score 0):

Updating Google Talk is not high on Google's priority list. The About section of Google Talk shows (C) 2005-2006!

Regarding switching between message windows of Google Talk, you can use Ctrl+Tab. It will cycle through Contact list and message windows. Its not THE ideal solution, but its better than nothing. :)